# Maximum number of useful indexes a table can have?

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

**The Meeting**

In a meeting last week the client was discussing how to make an important search page faster. The page searches on a single table (12 columns, 20 million rows) by asking for values (strings) on any field; it returns 50 rows (with pagination), starting with the specified criteria (each column can be ascending or descending). When the criteria doesn't match the existing indexes, the search becomes slow, and the client is not happy.

And then -- in the middle of the meeting -- the semi-technical analyst threw this one into the air: **Why don't we create all possible indexes on the table to make everything fast?**

I responded at once "No, there are too many and that would make the table really slow to modify, so we need to create few *cleverly* chosen indexes to do it". We ended up creating the most useful ones, and the page is now much faster. Problem solved.

**The Question**

But still... I keep thinking about that question and I wanted to have a better understanding of it, so here it is:

***In theory, how many possible useful indexes can I create on a table with N columns?***

I think that by useful we should consider (I can be wrong):

- Indexes not already covered by other ones: for example (a, b) should not be counted if (a, b, c) is included.
- In order to show multiple rows (not just equality) ascending and descending indexes should be counted as separate ones when they are part of a composite index. That is: (a) serves the same purpose of (a DESC), but (a, b) serves a different purpose than (a DESC, b).

So, a table with a single column (a) can have only a single index:

```
(a)
```

With two columns (a, b) I can have four *useful* indexes:

```
(a, b)
(b, a)
(a DESC, b)
(b DESC, a)
(a) -- already covered by #1
(b) -- already covered by #2
(a, b DESC) -- already coverred by #1 (reading index in reverse)
(b, a DESC) -- already covered by #2
(a DESC, b DESC) -- already covered by #3
(b DESC, a DESC) -- already covered by #4
(a DESC) -- already covered by #3
(b DESC) -- already covered by #4
```

With three columns (a, b, c):

```
(a, b, c)
(a, c, b)
(b, c, a)
(b, a, c)
(c, a, b)
(c, b, a)
...
```

Comment: How descending indexes are handled depends on the database.  You are also leaving out function-based indexes, full-text indexes, and other types of indexes.

Comment: Postgres is pretty good at combining multiple indexes in the same query, so you don't really need to index every possible combination (and DESC is not needed most of the time as Postgres can use an ASC index nearly as efficient as an DESC one)

Comment: But the underlying question is "how many *candidate keys* can a table have?" (in a *normalized* schema, upto 5NF)

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes, I decided to leave function-based indexes out. The question is limited to simple column combinations.

Comment: "In theory, how many possible useful indexes can I create on a table with N columns?" -> you can to calculate how usefull indexes are the so called selectifity with  `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT column) / COUNT(*)  FROM table`..Or for multi column selectifity  `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT column, column) / COUNT(*)  FROM table` ... If the number is close to 0 it's a bad candidate for a index if the number is close to 1 it's a very good candidate for a index.

Answer (score 3):

Let's say you have a table t with columns a, b, and c.

For the query

```
select a from t where b = 1 order by c;
```

the best index is on t(b,c,a), because you first look up values using b, then order results by c and have a in the results.

For this query:

```
select a from t where c = 1 order by b;
```

the best index is on t(c,b,a).

For this query:

```
select b from t where c = 1 order by a;
```

the best index is on t(c,a,b).

With more columns a query could look like this:

```
select a from t where b = 1 order by c, d, e;
```

and you'd best want an index on t(b,c,d,e,a).

While for

```
select a from t where b = 1 order by e, d, c;
```

you'd want an index on t(b,e,d,c,a).

So the maximal number of useful indexes for n columns is n!, i.e. all permutations.

This is for indexes on the mere columns alone. As Gordon Linoff has mentioned in the comments section to your request, you may also want function indexes (e.g. on t(upper(a),lower(b)). The number of usefull function indexes is theoretically unlimited. And yes, Gordon is also right about further index types.

So the final answer is that theoretically the number of useful indexes per table is unlimited.

Comment: This formula (n!) makes a lot of sense. However I see two things: 1) If the first query is modified to `select a from t where b = 1 order by c DESC;` the index `t(b,c,a)` is not useful anymore; we would need `t(b,c DESC,a)`. 2) In our page we don't use equality `b = 1` but we search for a range `b >= 1`.

Comment: A good DBMS doesn't care much about ASC and DESC in an index, because a tree can easily be traversed backwards. As to `>=` instead of `=`: it's still the same column, but the likelyhood of the index being used is reduced. A DBMS usually uses indexes only when it thinks that you are only accessing a few percentage of the table's rows.

Comment: Thanks. so if we consider N=12 (my case), my calculator tells me there are '479,001,600'  possible indexes. Half a billion. Not a minor number :)

Comment: Yes. And "unlimited" is even more :-) So far for the theory.

Answer (score 2):

All the other answers contain something valuable, but there is enough that I have to say about it to warrant a third one.

There is no exact answer to the question like you put it. In a way, it is like asking “What's the limit beyond which you would call a person crazy?” There is a large grey area.

My points are:

- What would happen if you add too many indexes:

  - Modifying the table gets substantially slower. Even with few indexes, data manipulation will already become an order of magnitude slower. If you ever want to `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE`, a table with all conceivable indexes would make such an operation glacially slow.
  - With many indexes, the query planner has to consider many different access paths, so planning the query will become slightly slower with any index you add. With very many indexes, it may well be that the planning overhead will make the query too slow even before the executor has started working.
- What can you do to reduce the number of indexes needed:

  - Look at the operators. If the operators `<`, `<=`, `>=` and `>` are never used, there is no point in adding indexes with descending columns.
  - Remember that an index on `(a, b, c)` can also be used for a query that only uses `a` in its condition, so you don't need an extra index on `(a)`.
- What is a practical way forward for you?

  I have two suggestions:

  1. One way it to add a simple index on each of your twelve columns.

     Twelve indexes are already quite a lot, but you are still not in the crazy range.

     PostgreSQL can use these indexes efficiently in a query with conditions on more than one column, and even if none of the conditions alone would be selective enough to warrant an index scan.

     This is because PostgreSQL has *bitmap index scans*. See this example from [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/using-explain.html):

     ```
     EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM tenk1 WHERE unique1 < 100 AND unique2 > 9000;

                                          QUERY PLAN
     -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      Bitmap Heap Scan on tenk1  (cost=25.08..60.21 rows=10 width=244)
        Recheck Cond: ((unique1 < 100) AND (unique2 > 9000))
        ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=25.08..25.08 rows=10 width=0)
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on tenk1_unique1  (cost=0.00..5.04 rows=101 width=0)
                    Index Cond: (unique1 < 100)
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on tenk1_unique2  (cost=0.00..19.78 rows=999 width=0)
                    Index Cond: (unique2 > 9000)
     ```

     Each index is scanned and a bitmap is formed that contains 1 for each row that matches the condition. Then the bitmaps are combined, and finally the rows are fetched from the table.
  2. The other idea is to use a [*Bloom filter*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/bloom.html).

     If the only operator in your conditions is `=`, you can

     ```
     CREATE EXTENSION bloom;
     ```

     and create a *single index `USING bloom` over all table columns*.

     Such an index can be used for queries with *any combination of columns* in the `WHERE` clause. The down side is that it is a lossy index, so you will get false positive results that have to be fetched and filtered out.

     It depends on your case, but this might be an elegant (and underestimated!) solution that balances query and update speed.

Comment: I didn't know about the bloom filter.

Answer (score 1):

> In theory, how many possible useful indexes can I create on a table with N columns?

Rather than answering this question *theoretically*, a *practical* answer is much better.

The first point to note is that *all* sequential searches should be avoided (unless the table is very small). By "very small", I mean, just a few rows (say, max 10). (However, even in such a table, a primary key is encouraged, to enforce uniqueness. This would, of course, be implemented as an index.)

Therefore, if the client has a valid search path, an index is required. If an existing index serves the purpose, that's OK; else, in all probability, an additional index is needed.

One transaction table in one application in my experience had 8 indexes. The client insisted on certain search paths, and so we had no choice but to provide them. Of course, we informed the client that updates would slow down, but the client found that acceptable. In reality, the slowdown in speed during updates wasn't appreciable.

So that is the approach suggested - warn the client accordingly.

It is important to verify, during design, that a SQL statement uses indexed search paths (for every accessed table), rather than searching sequentially. ORACLE has a tool for this, called `EXPLAIN PLAN`. Other DBs should also have similar tools.

Comment: Yes, I totaly agree with you, and our problem is (for the time being) resolved. But I still have the question. Any idea on a formula to determine how many indexes?

Comment: I'd consider anything up to a "few thousands" still small enough that a Seq Scan doesn't really matter - the better figure for such a threshold is however the number of _blocks_, not necessarily the number of rows.